# Best approach to localize different projects using the same namespace

Tags: c#, wpf

I'm trying to localize two different projects which share the same namespace.

The Resources files are in project A. Whenever I try to localize a control in project B I get this error:

Error   21  Cannot find the type 'Resources'. Note that type names are case sensitive.  C:\data\projects\UIDesktop\MainWindow.xaml

For both I'm adding this reference at the top of each xaml

xmlns:properties="clr-namespace:Gui.Properties"

Is this possible or should they have different namespaces altogether?

thanx in advance

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you only specify the namespace (like `"clr-namespace:Gui.Properties"`), it refers to this namespace in the current assembly. If you have the same namespace in another assembly, you need to specify the assembly name:

```
xmlns:properties="clr-namespace:Gui.Properties;assembly=MyAssembly"
```