# XAML Resx localization not working as expected

Tags: wpf, xaml, localization, resources, resx

I'm attempting to use a resx file to localize some strings I am using in a XAML file.  I've looked around at other documentation on the web, and they all seem to recommend a two part process:

1. Add a clr-namespace to your window, like this:
   `xmlns:props="clr-namespace:PJConfiguration.Properties"`
2. Use that namespace to localize your string like this:
   `Content="{x:Static props:Resources.SharedSettings}"`

I've done this, and also made sure that my resource classes are public, but I still get the following error from the XAML in step 2:

> Cannot find the type 'Resources'.

Does anyone know what else might be causing this problem?  Thanks in advance.

Comment: Not enough context, this technique does work, you can probably make it work in a clean project as well. But there is no way to tell what might be wrong in this case.

Comment: Any particular things you would like me to include?

Comment: Well, an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/) would be great.

Comment: Is your .resx file the default Resources.resx file inside the Properties directory of the Application assembly?

Comment: @Nero, your comment made me double check the resource files.  Someone had checked in an old copy of "resource.resx" instead of "resources.resx".  That file was causing problems.  Fixed this, and now it works!  Thanks!!

Comment: @Nero, if you add an answer, I'll mark it as correct. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check if your .resx file is the default Resources.resx file inside the Properties directory of the Application assembly. If that is, there is no reason XAML couldn't find the public class Resources from the correct namespace under local assembly.

Comment: Is there no way to do this if your .resx is not the default Resources.resx?

Answer (score 3):

In order to make the Resources visible to XAML, you have to make sure that the code generation mode for the resources is set to public. In VS, you find that setting in a ComboBox near the top of the Resources designer window.

For more information on using .Net resources in XAML, you might want to refer to these blog posts: http://wpfglue.wordpress.com/category/localization/

Comment: Thanks, I've already set the code generation mode to public as mentioned in my question statement. I'll check out the blog and see if there's anything extra there that might help.

Comment: Sorry, overlooked the part about the public. However, have you rebuilt the project since changing the access modifier to public? If the resources and the window which uses them are in the same assembly, sometimes the error in using the resources keeps the project from building, which has to happen before the resources can be found.

Comment: Yeah, I've rebuilt...even deleted the entire bin directory manually. No change.

Answer (score 1):

Try to specify the assembly name in Step 2 as recommended in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8240774/122005).

Comment: I've just added this, but it did not solve the problem.  I still get "Cannot find the type 'Resources'."